# Puma is reloading Rails application code before a restart is issued in production env

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma

After noticing weird exceptions during our deployment (we noticed new code that relied on migrations that were still running during deployment was already being served before we issued puma restart), we could confirm that puma is reloading application code as soon as we update the codebase via `git pull`, even tough we're running in production ENV and Puma should wait for the restart to be issued.

**UPDATE**: here's a short 1min video about what's going on:
https://www.loom.com/share/710d2d617f0746c8b418fc162a1c2016

OS: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Puma Version 4.3.0

Puma config:

```
shared_dir = "/var/www/app/shared"

workers 25
threads 1, 1

bind "unix://#{shared_dir}/tmp/sockets/puma-app.sock"

environment "production"

stdout_redirect "#{shared_dir}/log/puma.stdout.log", "#{shared_dir}/log/puma.stderr.log", true

pidfile "#{shared_dir}/tmp/pids/puma.pid"

preload_app!

before_fork do
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.disconnect! if defined?(ActiveRecord)
end

on_worker_boot do

  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection if defined?(ActiveRecord)

end
```

Puma socket (We're using [socket activation](https://github.com/puma/puma/blob/master/docs/systemd.md#socket-activation)):

```
[Unit]
Description=Puma HTTP Server Accept Sockets for app

[Socket]
SocketUser={{ param_user_name }}
SocketGroup={{ param_user_name }}
ListenStream=/var/www/app/shared/tmp/sockets/puma-app.sock

# Socket options matching Puma defaults
NoDelay=true
ReusePort=true
Backlog=1024

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

Expected behavior - Puma should not start serving new code immediately after we update the application's codebase with a git pull. It should wait for us to issue a sudo systemctl restart puma-app.service.

If we run a `git pull` manually in the application's codebase folder, we can confirm requests start seeing new code immediately, even tough no puma restart has been issued, and no puma restart is indicated in puma.stdout.log.

**Update: here's my Rails application.rb and production.rb**

```
# application.rb

# Enables garbage colletion data for New Relic
GC::Profiler.enable

require_relative 'boot'

require 'rails/all'

require 'connection_pool'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module MyApp

  class Application < Rails::Application

    config.before_initialize do

      ::REDIS = ConnectionPool.new(size: ENV['WORKER_PROCESS'].to_i) { Redis.new }

    end

    config.autoload_paths += %W(
      #{config.root}/lib
      #{config.root}/lib/middleware
    )

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    config.time_zone = 'Brasilia'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    config.i18n.default_locale = :'pt-br'

    # dynamic and custom error pages
    config.exceptions_app = self.routes

    # ActiveJob
    config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sidekiq

  end
end
```

```
# production.rb
Rails.application.configure do
  config.webpacker.check_yarn_integrity = false

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier

  config.assets.css_compressor = :sass 

  config.assets.compile = false

  config.assets.digest = true

  config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX

  config.active_storage.service = :local

  config.force_ssl = true

  config.log_level = :info

  Rails.application.routes.default_url_options = {host: 'example.com'}

  config.action_mailer.asset_host = 'https://example.com'
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {...}

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where your change is (e.g. perhaps is part of the path that gets loaded lazily and was not loaded at the time, perhaps autoloading/caching for a specific case does not work as intended...) but also how you configured rails in your `env/production.rb` or `application.rb`, Puma or other rails servers can 'pickup' your changes even without restart.

To be safe sometimes you might want to split your changes to migration and then code that uses them (ie have 2 step rollout) ...

**EDIT**: 
To be sure what is going on you can execute this:

```
# does below command returns a list containing use ActionDispatch::Reloader ?
bundle exec rake middleware RAILS_ENV=production
```

Comment: we just recently migrated from Unicorn to Puma (about 2 months), and we relied heavily on this behavior (which worked great). I don't see any documentation on Puma about this behavior (everywhere it mentions about restart to pickup new code), and I can't imagine what configuration we might have in env/production or application.rb that could be causing this. Could you elaborate?

Comment: can you share your configs from application.rb / production.rb related to class caching, autoload paths, ...
Also what is the specific change that gets picked up? (you could also try that specific change on unicorn and see if it behaves differently)

Comment: I updated the question with both files; the specific change that gets picked right away before a restart is any view.html.erb file.

Comment: Also just updated with a video
https://www.loom.com/share/710d2d617f0746c8b418fc162a1c2016

Comment: thanks for the video - I've added an edit to the answer

Comment: Update: I ran `bundle exec rake middleware RAILS_ENV=production` and no, there's no Reloader in the middleware chain.

Comment: hm, not sure what is going on from here. I would add some logs to `before_fork` `after_fork` in puma config or try control app (in puma config put something like):
`activate_control_app('tcp://127.0.01:9000', auth_token: 'top_secret')` and then if you go: `/stats?secret=top_secret` and see if anything is weird there.
See: https://dev.to/amplifr/monitoring-puma-web-server-with-prometheus-and-grafana-5b5o